# In Pandas, I want to group by a common element and get a list of the elements between them

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group by a common element and get a list of the elements between them.

The data set i have is below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Type': {0: 'S', 1: '1', 2: '3', 3: '3', 4: '2', 5: 'S', 6: '4', 7: 'S', 8: '4', 9: '5', 10: '6', 11: 'S', 12: '2', 13: 'S'}})

   Type
0     S
1     1
2     3
3     3
4     2
5     S
6     4
7     S
8     4
9     5
10    6
11    S
12    2
13    S
```

I can perform this grouping using more_itertools, but i want to know if there is a more pandaic way to accomplish this task:

Expected output ( I used more_itertools for this, but is there a more pandaic way?)

```
import more_itertools
pred = lambda x: x == "S"
list(more_itertools.split_before(df.T.values.tolist()[0], pred)) 

[['S', '1', '3', '3', '2'],
 ['S', '4'],
 ['S', '4', '5', '6'],
 ['S', '2'],
 ['S']]
```

on a side note, can you use groupby to group between the elements, so each group is just like the output above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': {0: 'S', 1: '1', 2: '3', 3: '3', 4: '2', 5: 'S', 6: '4', 7: 'S', 8: '4', 9: '5', 10: '6', 11: 'S', 12: '2', 13: 'S'}})

df['seqnum'] = (df['Type'] == 'S').cumsum()
df.groupby('seqnum')['Type'].apply(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a Series which indicates which rows are in which groups:

```
groupidx = (df.Type == 'S').cumsum()
grouped = df.groupby(groupidx)
result = grouped.Type.apply(list)
```

The result is:

```
1    [S, 1, 3, 3, 2]
2             [S, 4]
3       [S, 4, 5, 6]
4             [S, 2]
5                [S]
```